# Best way to get substrings of a longer string

Tags: c#, string, substring

What's the best way in c# to extract subtrings of a longer string like:

```
String str = "Car: volvo Wheels: 4 doors: 5";
```

Lets say I want the values volvo, 4, 5 inserted into

```
string car
string wheels
string doors

string newStr = str.Substring(read.IndexOf(':'), read.IndexOf(" "));
```

then after I have extracted the first String I'd remove that part

```
string str = strRemove(0, read.IndexOf(" ") + 1);
```

Then repeat this until everything was extracted. It's just tedious, and thought there would be a better way.

Comment: What research have you done so far? Did you, for example, do a search on the web or MSDN for the text "string substring"? Are you just asking for someone to do that search for you? Or did you find something but are having trouble understanding how to use it? Do you have a precise specification of the source string? E.g. will it always have the text "Car:", "Wheels:", and "doors:" in it, and are you always trying to extract the space-delimited words after each of those fields?

Comment: I did some rigorously Substring() and Remove(). It worked but seemed dubious.

Comment: Then please show us what you have done so far. Provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've got now, along with a clear explanation of what that code does, and how that's different from what you want it to do.

Comment: IndexOf() find the new symbol, is there a way to find the next occurance of that symbol? So that I with two IndexOf() could sorta extract the strings because they have a space at the beginning and end of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about...

```
string rawData = "Car: volvo Wheels: 4 doors: 5";
        var words = Regex.Split(rawData, @"\w+:").Select(x => x.Trim()).Where(x => x.Length > 0).ToList();
        var car = words[0];
        var wheels = words[1];
        var doors = words[2];
```

Comment: Simple and very efficient. Thanks alot! Did not realize it could be done so easily. Guess I gotta read up on my Lambda Expressions!

Comment: This wont work if the car name has a space in it like "Alfa Romeo"

Comment: @MikeHixson: nor will any of the other suggestions (including mine). Though, the regex approaches are more easily fixed, of course.

Comment: I just added an answer that would cover the case when the car name has a space in it.

Answer (score 1):

Try Regex

```css
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "Car: volvo Wheels: 4 doors: 5";

            string pattern = @"Car:\s+(?'Car'[^\s]+)\s+Wheels:\s+(?'Wheels'[^\s]+)\s+doors:\s+(?'Doors'[^\s]+)";

            Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
            string car = match.Groups["Car"].Value;
            string wheels = match.Groups["Wheels"].Value;
            string doors = match.Groups["Doors"].Value;
        }
    }
}
​
```

Answer (score 1):

Lacking better detail, it's hard to know for sure what the right answer here is. But, assuming the labels "Car:", "Wheel:", and "doors:" are invariant, and you want to extract the variable values after each label, something like the following should accomplish your needs:

```
static readonly Regex _regex = new Regex(
    @"Car: (?<car>[^ ]*) Wheels: (?<wheels>[^ ]*) doors: (?<doors>[^ ]*)",
    RegexOptions.Compiled);

void SomeMethod(string text)
{
    Match match = _regex.Match(text);

    if (!match.Success)
    {
        return;
    }

    string car = match.Groups["car"].Value;
    string wheels = match.Groups["wheels"].Value;
    string doors = match.Groups["doors"].Value;
}
```

You can generalize the technique to any kind of string with a regular pattern of construction.

Answer (score 0):

The most robust way to do this would be to use a regular expression. Others have provided regular expressions as solutions, but they do not cover the case where the car name has a space in it as in "Alfa Romeo". This solution would work better in those cases.

```
    string input = "Car: volvo Wheels: 4 doors: 5";

    Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"Car: (?<car>.+) Wheels: (?<wheels>\d+) doors: (?<doors>\d+)");

    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["car"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["wheels"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["doors"].Value);
```